# Как работает Акинатор?

Tags: нейронные-сети

Наверное многие знают сайт-игру которая угадывает задуманного персонажа - Акинатор. Каким образом данная программа обучается, и как туда попадают новые вопросы и персонажи ?

Comment: Скорее всего, там у каждого персонажа сделана характеристика по общим тегам и вопросам и скрипт выбирает персонажа с наибольшим количеством совпадений. Если таких несколько, то он задает дополнительные вопросы, чтобы получить больше информации и выбрать одного. P.S. Это не точно что именно так, но меньшую версию выше описанной системы мы пытались когда-то реализовать.

Answer (score 1):

Хорошая [статья](https://geektimes.ru/post/84364/), где автор вполне успешно расколол принцип работы Акинатора. Вкратце: строим дерево вопрос-ответ, чтобы избежать проблем с ошибками/неточностями используем [байесовский подход](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0), а чтобы максимально эффективно сужать круг поиска - используем [информационную энтропию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%8D%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/180192)

Comment: @insolor Готово.